# Row limt with Groupings and fixed table layout ,in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I do know sometimes I need to think out of the box rather than sticking with that seem-impossible way out. I have to achieve a report (not complicated I guess, but for me I have no more idea how to get) 
Well, the details are as follow:

The report is kind of invoice type.
Like an usual report, it has header, body and footer. In my scenario, there is no footer. Only the report header and the body. The header is ok. The Body consist of a table.

My data rows starts from row 3( because I add some content in row no 1, inside the list, as for row no 2, I have my table column header). So, actually my data row(which is directly retrieved from dataset) is at row no 3. The header repeat correctly. In fact, the table is displaying exactly as I wanted. I have two groups in my table. One is group by ItemCode, and then sort by ItemCode and Department number.

I have subtotal of value by ItemCode and Grandtotal after that. So, there are three rows for my data: one directly retrieved from dataset, one for subtotal and one for grandtotal. The problem is here:
I can't limit the number of row because of the groups. The row number rankings are messed up and that's why I can't limit. The resulting outcome is having inconsistency in showing numbers of rows. 
For example I want to limit 10, but in some page, it displays 10(correct), but in the next page it might becomes 12 or 8 or even 4. That is one thing. Another is that I want to replace the missing rows(2 rows in this case) with blank rows if the it just displays only 8 rows(example). My idea is to maintain the same layout of the table in every page.

As for now, I have no more idea how to achieve my desired result. If I really cannot use row limit then how to do next. I have been researching about that for quite a long time, but still cannot get away with a solution.
I hope I have made myself clear explaining what is going on. Some part is not clear enough, then get back to me. I will try my best to explain more.
If anyone has any suggestions, please kindly share. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: please format your question, make readable.! Thanks.

Comment: So far no idea or comment yet. I guess It is that impossible to do with SSRS.